# How to find and replace two multiple values in the same row by excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose the value 4 must not be with value 18 in all rows of my data.

**How can I replace the value 4 with any value for all rows that have value 18?**

See the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, I am suggesting a VBA Macro to automate this task. I assume you are searching for actual Number 4 and not a character 4. So if it's 44 it should be ignored and not attempted to be replaced.

In your worksheet press ALT + F11 to access VBA Editor. From **Insert** Menu insert a **Module**. Double click on the Module name in left pane to access the code editor. Now paste the following code into it.

```
Sub Replace4()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColCount As Integer
Dim i, j, k
Const Replaced = 0
Set MyRange = Range("B2:F12")

RowCount = MyRange.Rows.Count
ColCount = MyRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To RowCount
    If MyRange.Columns(1).Cells(i) = 18 Then
        For j = 2 To ColCount
            If MyRange.Columns(j).Cells(i) = 4 Then
               MyRange.Columns(j).Cells(i).Value = Replaced
            End If
        Next j
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Note that you should set the Constant Replaced (see `Const Replaced = 0` ) to the intended value and specify your range at line `Set MyRange = Range("B2:F12")`

Ensure that the first column of this range is indeed the columns in which you are checking for presence of 18.

Save the Excel sheet as xlsm for Excel 2007 and above (Macro Enabled worksheet).

Now in your worksheet press ALT + F8 to access the Macro dialog box and run this Macro named Replace4

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot ,, Its work .
Another Ask For the same Question , if i want to replace "Randomly" only 30% of Number 4.

Comment: It should be possible it may require a different approach and some code changes. Since you have accepted the answer, this becomes a sort of reference baseline Q&A post for anyone having similar problem in future. If you have a different requirement, I suggest that you ask a new question rather than editing this again.

Comment: Can you see this is Question 
https://superuser.com/questions/1270027/how-to-find-and-replace-randomly-with-rate-of-two-multiple-values-in-the-same-ro