# How to find and replace randomly with rate of two multiple values in the same row by excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose that value 18 and value 4 are in the same row but the value 4 must be only 70% with value 18 in all rows of my data. How can I correct that and change only 30% of the value 4 Randomly with any value for all rows that have value 18? See the picture below:

[image: Sample of My Question]

Comment: Are you looking at 30% per row or 30% overall count of 4 where first column is 18?

Comment: Yes, 30% overall count of 4 where first column is 18.

Comment: I mean suppose that my Data have 120 rows consist 18 with 4 , i want to replace randomly only 30% of 4 from this rows with any value after replacement Must my data have 84 rows consist 18 with 4 .

Comment: So it's 30% of Row Count (where there may be even at least one 4 against 18) not the 4's count?

Comment: Yes of course .

Comment: Does 4 reoccur across columns or you are specifically intended to check only against a single column? If single column, then 30% of 4's count and row count would match.

Comment: Yes Single column ,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how I understand your question, try this code and confirm if this works for you.

In this example sample data is in B1:F23. The 4's are checked only in 3rd column.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to access VBA Editor. From Insert Menu insert a Module. Double click on the module name in Left Pane to access it's Code Editor. Now put the following macro code in it.

```vb
Sub Replace430()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ColCount As Integer
Dim MyArray() As Variant

Dim i, j, k, percent30 As Long
Dim Count4 As Long
Const Replaced = 0   'Set Replaced Value
Const found = 18     'Set Find Value
Const Mycol = 3      'Correctly set the Column Number of Column in Range where 4 is to be checked
Set MyRange = Range("B2:F23")

RowCount = MyRange.Rows.Count
ColCount = MyRange.Columns.Count
'Get number of 4's againts 18
For i = 1 To RowCount
    If MyRange.Columns(1).Cells(i) = found Then
        For j = Mycol To Mycol
            If MyRange.Columns(j).Cells(i) = 4 Then
               Count4 = Count4 + 1
            End If
        Next j
    End If

Next i

ReDim MyArray(Count4 - 1, 2)
k = 0
For i = 1 To RowCount
    If MyRange.Columns(1).Cells(i) = found Then
        For j = Mycol To Mycol
            If MyRange.Columns(j).Cells(i) = 4 Then
               MyArray(k, 1) = i
               MyArray(k, 2) = j
               k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    End If

Next i

percent30 = 0.3 * Count4

Dim shufflearray()
ReDim shufflearray(Count4 - 1)
For i = 0 To Count4 - 1
    shufflearray(i) = i
Next i

'Shuffle the shufflearray() below


    Dim N As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant


    Randomize
    For N = LBound(shufflearray) To UBound(shufflearray)
        j = CLng(((UBound(shufflearray) - N) * Rnd) + N)

        If N <> j Then
            Temp = shufflearray(N)
            shufflearray(N) = shufflearray(j)
            shufflearray(j) = Temp
        End If
    Next N

'Use randomised values from shufflearray as array subscript to replace only 30% of 4's
For i = 0 To percent30 - 1
    MyRange.Columns(MyArray(shufflearray(i), 2)).Cells(MyArray(shufflearray(i), 1)).Value = Replaced
Next i


End Sub
```

Set youir range correctly at statement `Set MyRange = Range("B2:F23")`
Set column number correctly at `Const Mycol = 3`

Save the file as Macro Enabled Workbook and from the worksheet press ALT + F8 to access Macro Run dialog box. Run this Macro Replace430().

Test it further and confirm. As per your comments this assumes that the 4's occur only in 3rd column of the selected range. 4's anywhere else are ignored for the time being.

[image]